# In SSAS What if I define relationship between Fact and Dimension in Dimesion usage tab rather than DSV

Tags: ssas

I am new to SSAS So I don't have basic knowledge about it.
While going through some example ,I had a question that :
Suppose I have many Dimension tables and fact Tables,In the Data Source View SSAS will automatically identify primary key relationship and create some relationships,But apart from those relationship in Data Source View , we create some New relationships which are not identified by SSAS.

What will happen if instead of creating relationship between fact and Dimension in Data Source View,I create relationship in The Dimension usage Tab.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have defined relationships in DSV, you may still need to define them in the Dimension Usage tab, such as for Referenced or Many-to-Many relationships.

Even if you have not defined the relationship in the DSV, you can still manually create a relationship in the Dimension Usage tab.

The benefit of creating relationships in the DSV are as follows:

- Self-documentation of code
- Helping the SSDT wizards define business intelligence

Comment: So if i define in Dimension Usage tab and not in DSV is it ok?

Comment: Yes, it will work, and there will be no performance difference, but you do loose the documentation aspect of the dsv